# How to show an image in MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I wonder if there is a way to show an image in MongoDB Compass.

I have this document:
[image: MongoDB document - last field is a binary coming from an image]

Last field, is a binary, which represents an image.

What I need is to show the image inside the Compass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't support that, but please submit this idea to https://feedback.mongodb.com/forums/924283-compass

Comment: Thanks @AlenaKhineika I left the idea @ [link](https://feedback.mongodb.com/forums/924283-compass/suggestions/40423987-to-be-able-to-show-images-contained-in-document-fi)